# What's the etymology of spam when talking about bulk unsolicited messages?

Tags: etymology, internet

What does *spam* stand for, when talking about unsolicited (mostly advertisement) messages? The nearest possibility I found was "Stupid Pointless Annoying Messages" but it seems like too colorful to be a proper acronym. When was it first used to mean "unsolicited messages"?

Comment: Look it up on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(electronic)#Etymology).

Comment: I'm very familiar with the Monty Python sketch (and song) but don't see how that is a connection to bulk unwanted e-mails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SPAM](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Spam&searchmode=none) is a proprietary name registered by Geo. A. Hormel & Co. in U.S., 1937; probably a conflation of spiced ham. Soon extended to other kinds of canned meat.

> **In the sense of "Internet junk mail" it was coined by Usenet users after March 31, 1993**, when Usenet administrator Richard Depew inadvertently posted the same message 200 times to a discussion group. The term had been used in online text games, and ultimately **it is from a 1970 sketch on the British TV show "Monty Python's Flying Circus" wherein a reading of a restaurant's menu devolves into a humorous song consisting (almost exclusively) of the word 'spam.'**

[How the Word “Spam” Came to Mean “Junk Message](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/09/how-the-word-spam-came-to-mean-junk-message/)

Comment: Is there any link to this event?

Comment: What event do you mean?

Comment: "it was coined by Usenet users after March 31, 1993", I'm trying to google it, but only references appear, not the original message.

Comment: @Braiam See citations 25 and 26 (as I write) in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 8):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Spam&searchmode=none) traces it to a usenet post as described in Josh61's answer. The [post in question](http://groups.google.com/groups?hl=en&lr=lang_en&threadm=1993Mar31.192731.3167@mnemosyne.cs.du.edu&rnum=1&prev=/groups?hl=en&lr=lang_en&selm=1993Mar31.192731.3167%2540mnemosyne.cs.du.edu) was by Joel Furr and reads:

> ARMM: n.  A USENET posting robot created by Dick Depew of Munroe Falls, Ohio.
>      Originally intended to serve as a means of controlling posts through 
>      anon servers (see also {anon servers}).  Transformed by programming
>      ineptitude into a monster of Frankenstein proportions, **it broke loose
>      on the night of March 31, 1993 and proceeded to spam news.admin.policy
>      with something on the order of 200 messages** in which it attempted, and
>      failed, to cancel its own messages.  This produced a recursive chain
>      of messages each of which tacked on:

I found [this page](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/09/how-the-word-spam-came-to-mean-junk-message) which offers some (unsourced) alternatives:

> - First documented case among Usenet users was March 31, 1993.  This is often incorrectly stated to be the first usage of the term spam as referring to spam messages.  This first Usenet case came when Richard Depew, who had been playing with some moderation software, accidentally ended up posting around 200 duplicate messages in a row to news.admin.policy newsgroup.  The first person to call this spam is thought to be Joel Furr on March 31, 1993.  Depew himself when he apologized referred to his messages as spam.
> - A more likely “first use” of the word spam, referring to certain electronic messages, comes from MUDs (multi-user-dungeons).  This was a sort of real time multi-person shared environment; a somewhat primitive version of The Sims Online or Second Life and the like.  In it, users could chat and interact with other people, locations, and objects, as well as create objects and share them with the community.  Basically a really advanced chat room.   The name MUD comes from the fact that it reminded people of certain aspects of Dungeons and Dragons.  In any event, spamming was used here to refer to a few different things including: flooding the computer with random data; “spam the database” by flooding it with new objects; and flooding a chat session with a ton of unwanted text.  Basically, anything that had to do with filling other member’s accounts with unwanted electronic junk.   One of the earliest documented uses of the word spam from MUDders comes from 1990 when they were, ironically enough, discussing the origins of the word “spam” as referring to electronic junk messages.  Undocumented sources say it had been around quite a bit before that among MUDders, which is evidenced by the content of the documented message.
> - Others say that the term originated on Bitnet’s Relay, which was a very early chat system in the 1980s.  Supposedly, users would occasionally come on and annoy other users with unwanted text, including the actual SPAM SPAM SPAM song from Monty Python.
> - Another similar chat system TRS-80 also reported the same phenomenon and also called it spam.  Both these latter two chat system origins are not documented, but numerous former users of these systems have stated they remember this term being use commonly among users of these systems.

Some more reflections on the origin of the term can be found on Brad Templeton's blog, [here](http://www.templetons.com/brad/spam/spam25.html). They basically reiterate the above but are actually sourced.

Answer (score 5):

It comes from a [sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anwy2MPT5RE) in the British TV show Monty Python's Flying Circus, set in a cafe in which (almost) every dish included Spam.

Comment: [Don't forget the song!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UO7HY7Nz398)

Comment: How could I forget the song? :)

It was part of the sketch I mentioned.

Comment: An element of the Monty Python joke is the fact that spam was (and still is) a low-status form of reconstituted ham that no eatery with pretensions to fine dining would consider including in its menu, let alone in so many different forms.

Answer (score 1):

In the [beginning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8huXkSaL7o),

> Well, there's egg and bacon,
>   [...]
>   Egg, bacon, sausage and spam
>   [...]
>   Spam, sausage, spam, spam, spam, bacon, spam tomato and spam
>   (etc.)
>   [stlyrics.com](http://www.stlyrics.com/songs/m/montypython9364/spamsong313328.html)
>
> (**Choir**: *Spam! Spam! Spam! Spam! Lovely Spam! Lovely Spam!*)

Then came the internet.  At first is was dominated by professionals getting academic work done.  This meant people were expected to act professional.  Also, it was slow.  So anything that wasted your time was extremely painful.

Then came automation.  Accidents happened and some posts turned out to be repetitive or meaningless<sup>[1](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/09/how-the-word-spam-came-to-mean-junk-message/)</sup>.  Some who complained about this expressed their displeasure by comparing it to the Monty Python song quoted above.  People soon realized that the only consequence from these accidental postings was complaining.  And a passive aggressive weapon was born.

The result of this behavior has been called floods, junk, and simply noise.  But spam, at least to me, was the first internet meme.  I remember trolls that had obviously combined their copy and paste buffers with key repetition to repeat the word spam over and over.  Giving them the power to waste your time without even having to bother to type let alone think.  Other than the Monty Python bit itself this is what most likely popularized the usage.

This is why so much of the internet is moderated today.  Users have the power to downvote this answer exactly because I have the power to make it nothing but:

Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam ...

And that only cost me 8 keystrokes.  This is why, despite helping the US win World War II, Hormel, the makers of spam, inventors of the word, owners of the trade mark, gets second billing in the definition of spam:

> **spam** *noun*
>
> 1. irrelevant or inappropriate messages sent on the Internet to a large number of recipients.
> 2. trademark - 
>      a canned meat product made mainly from ham.
>
> *verb*
>
> 1. send the same message indiscriminately to (large numbers of recipients) on the Internet.
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spam%20definition)

So either the internet owes Hormel an apology or Hormel has secretly created the greatest viral marketing campaign of all time.

> (**Choir**: *Spam! Spam! Spam! Spam! Lovely Spam! Lovely Spam!*)